# pandas groupby, count occurance of each value

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
  start_time                 is_set
0 2017-03-24 11:08:50        False
1 2017-03-24 11:08:50        False
2 2017-03-24 12:09:00        True
3 2017-03-24 12:20:00        False
4 2017-03-24 12:25:10        False
5 2017-03-23 15:30:16        False
6 2017-03-23 15:50:35        False
7 2017-03-23 21:39:08        True
8 2017-03-23 21:41:20        True
9 2017-03-23 23:31:34        True
```

I want to group the rows per hour and count the number of True and Falses for each hour.
Result should be:

```
  start_time                 False     True
0 2017-03-24 11              2         0 
1 2017-03-24 12              2         1
2 2017-03-23 15              2         0
3 2017-03-23 21              0         2
4 2017-03-23 23              0         1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['start_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H'), df['is_set'])#.reset_index()
```